# c# vs 2017 mocking var property with return inside

Tags: c#, properties, mocking, nsubstitute

i'm trying to mock a custom variable inside a class that's readonly and has a return inside the get.

```
public class BaseController
{
    public string Local
    {
        return GlobalVariable.Local
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod()
{
    var baseControllerMock = Substitute.For<BaseController>();
    baseControllerMock.Local.Returns("local");
}
```

My problem it's that even if i use ReturnsForAnyArgs when it goes inside the return I tired to look for the global variable and it breaks because

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' since the GlobalVariable is null.

I also tryed to mock the global Variable

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod()
{
    var baseControllerMock = Substitute.For<BaseController>();
    var globalVarMock = Substitute.For<GlobalVariable>();
    globalVarMock.Local.returns("local");
    baseControllerMock.Local.Returns("local");
}
```

but when it goes to the return it says that it is still null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making `BaseController.Locale` `virtual`.

NSubstitute can only work with [overridable members of classes](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/creating-a-substitute/#substituting-infrequently-and-carefully-for-classes). If you add [NSubstitute.Analyzers](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/nsubstitute-analysers/) to your test project it will help detect cases that can not be substituted at compile time.

---

*Edit from comments:* This tests passes without error for me:

```
    public static class GlobalVariable { public static string Local = "hi"; }
    public class BaseController
    {
        public virtual string Local { get { return GlobalVariable.Local; } }
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod() {
        var baseControllerMock = Substitute.For<BaseController>();
        baseControllerMock.Local.Returns("local");
    }
```

Comment: public class BaseController { public virtual string Local { return GlobalVariable.Local } } Like this? I've never used the virtual part

Comment: @RicardoSanchezSantos I'm not sure from your example if you are after a field or property? For a property having `public virtual string Local { get { return GlobalVariable.Local; } }` will pass your first test (although need to change `Locale` to `Local` in the test to get it to compile).

Comment: the locale part was a typo, my bad, i already edit it so it says local like it should be, also y already add de virtual part `public virtual string Local { get { return GlobalVariable.Local; }  }` and i ran the test again, but it still send me the NullReferance when it enters to the return

Comment: Hi @RicardoSanchezSantos, I have updated the answer with an example that passes on my machine. (Although I used `[Fact]` instead of `[TestMethod]` as I have XUnit rather than MSTest installed in my experimental project :) )

Comment: I also really recommend adding [NSubstitute.Analyzers](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/nsubstitute-analysers/) to your test project. It will let you know at compile time if something can't be substituted (e.g. because it is non-virtual class member).